# Merge Sort - return a new array instead of copying merged array to input array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I'm trying to implement a very naive version of Merge Sort (not considering all the optimizations for this purpose) where my goal is to return a new copy of the merged array rather than the traditional way of passing the input array by reference and copying the merged elements into it.

To that end, my code is as below:

```
vector<int> merge(vector<int> left, vector<int> right)
{
    vector<int> result;
    int leftIdx = 0;
    int rightIdx = 0;
    int resultIdx = 0;

    while (leftIdx < left.size() && rightIdx < right.size()) {
        if (left[leftIdx] < right[rightIdx]) {
            result[resultIdx++] = left[leftIdx++];
        } else {
            result[resultIdx++] = right[rightIdx++];
        }
    }

    while (leftIdx < left.size()) {
        result[resultIdx++] = left[leftIdx++];
    }

    while (rightIdx < right.size()) {
        result[resultIdx++] = right[rightIdx++];
    }

    return result;
}

vector<int> MergeSort(vector<int> intArr)
{
    vector<int> recresult;

    // base - if array is of length 1, nothing to do, return it as is
    if (intArr.size() == 1) {
        return intArr;
    } else {
        int mid = intArr.size() / 2;
        // copy left half
        vector<int> leftArr(intArr.begin(), intArr.begin() + mid);
        // copy right half
        vector<int> rightArr(intArr.begin() + mid, intArr.end());

        MergeSort(leftArr);
        MergeSort(rightArr);

        recresult = merge(leftArr, rightArr);
    }

    return recresult;
}
```

1. I know that this array from merge is a local array and hence I'm returning it to mergesort which will in turn return it to main. 
   Am I wrong in assuming that this is not getting passed into and out from 
   subsequent recursive calls?
2. My test input to this code is {1,0,9}. I should be getting {0,1,9} but I get 32767.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You should probably use a const reference (`const vector<int> &intArr`) as the argument to `MergeSort()` to save on copying without modifying the original array.  The `merge()` might take const references too.  One simple way to achieve the 'sort into new vector' requirement is to copy into a new vector before sorting that.  You need to think about the return type carefully — or maybe I do.  If you're passing megabyte vectors, there's an awful lot of copying going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for `merge` - you should pass const references to arguments, otherwise you make too many unnecessary copies. Also you get out of bound access to `result` as you create in empty and accessing by index. And it is not a good idea to use `int` for index. So simplified version could be:

```
vector<int> merge(const vector<int> &left, const vector<int> &right)
{
    vector<int> result;
    auto lit = left.begin();
    auto rit = right.begin();
    while( lit != left.end() || rit != right.end() ) {
        bool lft = false;
        if( rit == right.end() )
            lft = true;
        else {
            if( lit != left.end() )
                lft = *lit < *rit;
        }
        result.push_back( lft ? *lit++ : *rit++ );
   }
   return result;
}
```

or version that closer to your:

```
vector<int> merge(const vector<int> &left, const vector<int> &right)
{
    vector<int> result( left.size() + right.size() );
    auto rst = result.begin();
    auto lit = left.begin();
    auto rit = right.begin();
    while( lit != left.end() && rit != right.end() )
        *rst++ = *lit < *rit ? *lit++ : *rit++;

    std::copy( lit, left.end(), rst );
    std::copy( rit, right.end(), rst );
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I was stepping through the debugger to see what's happening, and I noticed it much, much later that you're right. Empty array is a problem I did not tackle.  Thanks for the comments and the answer. However what purpose does the `left=true` serve? Is it to say only left array exists? you're assigning a bool value to a *const* vector<int> variable.

Comment: @Raaj there is a boolean flag that I called `left` - the same way as vector. I renamed it to avoid compilation error, but forgot to do that at one place.

Answer (score 3):

The recursive calls to `MergeSort` do nothing, because `intArr` is taken by value *(copied)* and you're not using the result value.

Something like this should work:

```
auto newLeft = MergeSort(leftArr);
auto newRight = MergeSort(rightArr);

recresult = merge(newLeft, newRight);
```

---

As Slava mentioned in the comments, you also have UB when accessing `result`, because its `size` is 0:

```
vector<int> result; // size = 0
// ...
result[resultIdx++] = left[leftIdx++]; // UB!
```

You should invoke [`std::vector::resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) before accessing the elements using `operator[]`.

Comment: There is UB for using out of bounds for `result` as well